Type Mismatch on Rust Warp Handler Response
I'm new in Rust, I don't have much knowledge about rust so don't mind me if I sound stupid.
My problem is when I directly return response_body it gives a mismatch errormismatched types
expected struct WithStatus<String>
found struct warp::http::Response<String>
And now I can fix this by adding with_status but it causes another problem, it won't have the expected content_type it always returns text/plain.
use warp::Filter;
use std::convert::Infallible;
use warp::http::{ Response, StatusCode };
use reqwest::Client;
use reqwest::Url;
use tracing::{ info, error };
use tracing_subscriber::FmtSubscriber;
use colored::*;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use warp::reply::Reply;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    dotenv().ok();

    let subscriber = FmtSubscriber::builder().with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO).finish();
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber).expect("setting default subscriber failed");

    let cors_proxy = warp::path("proxy").and(warp::query::query()).and_then(handle_request);

    let port = std::env::var("PORT").unwrap_or("3030".to_string()).parse();

    use std::net::{ IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr };

    let addr = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0)), port.unwrap());
    warp::serve(cors_proxy).run(addr).await;
}

async fn handle_request(
    query: std::collections::HashMap<String, String>
) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, Infallible> {
    let target_url = query.get("url").cloned();
    let referer_url = query.get("referer").cloned().unwrap_or_default();
    let origin_url = query.get("origin").cloned().unwrap_or_default();
    let proxy_all = query.get("all").cloned().unwrap_or_default();

    info!(
        "Incoming request: url={} referer={} origin={}",
        target_url.clone().unwrap_or_default().cyan(),
        referer_url.clone().magenta(),
        origin_url.clone().green()
    );

    if target_url.is_none() {
        error!("Invalid URL");
        return Ok(warp::reply::with_status("Invalid URL".to_string(), StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST));
    }

    let target_url = target_url.unwrap();

    let client = Client::new();
    let response_result = client
        .get(&target_url)
        .header("Referer", referer_url.clone())
        .header("Origin", origin_url.clone())
        .send().await;

    if let Err(e) = response_result {
        error!("Request error: {}", e.to_string().red());
        return Ok(warp::reply::with_status(e.to_string(), StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }

    let response = response_result.unwrap();
    let status = StatusCode::from_u16(response.status().as_u16()).unwrap();
    let content_type = response
        .headers()
        .get("Content-Type")
        .map(|v| v.to_str().unwrap_or_default().to_string())
        .unwrap_or("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl".to_string());

    let mut body = response.text().await.unwrap_or_default();

    if target_url.contains(".m3u8") {
        let target_url_trimmed = Url::parse(&target_url)
            .ok()
            .and_then(|u| {
                let mut parts = u.path().split('/').collect::<Vec<_>>();
                parts.pop(); // Remove the last part (.m3u8)
                Some(parts.join("/"))
            })
            .unwrap_or_default();
        let encoded_url = urlencoding::encode(&referer_url);
        let encoded_origin = urlencoding::encode(&origin_url);

        body = body
            .split('\n')
            .map(|line| {
                if line.starts_with("#") || line.trim().is_empty() {
                    return line.to_string();
                } else if proxy_all == "yes" && line.starts_with("http") {
                    return format!("{}?url={}", query.get("url").unwrap(), line);
                }
                format!(
                    "?url={}{}{}{}",
                    urlencoding::encode(&target_url_trimmed),
                    line,
                    if !origin_url.is_empty() {
                        format!("&origin={}", encoded_origin)
                    } else {
                        String::new()
                    },
                    if !referer_url.is_empty() {
                        format!("&referer={}", encoded_url)
                    } else {
                        String::new()
                    }
                )
            })
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .join("\n");
    }

    let response_body = Response::builder()
        .status(status)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Content-Type", content_type.clone())
        .body(body)
        .unwrap();

    Ok(warp::reply::with_status(response_body.into_body(), status))
}

Now I have tried using with_header but it just don't work. It returns the same mismatch error and if I use
    Ok(warp::reply::with_status(response_body.into_body(), status))

It returns text/plain instead of the expected content-type

I don't know warp well, but your early returns should probably be return Err(…); not return Ok(…); and the return type adjusted accordingly.

Please remove anything that's not necessary to reproduce the error. In other words make your example a minimal reproducible example.
